# I did ridge regression and i am confused with coefficients

Tags: regression-coefficients, ridge-regression

> ridd=lm.ridge(mariner~o1+o2+o3,q,lambda=0.001)
>
> ridd

```
                     o1            o2            o3
```

34.7597607381  0.0001989008  0.0393011905 -1.7954157979

> ridd$coef

```
     o1          o2          o3
```

0.03535042  2.35304425 -2.93190172

So my question is what is the difference between both the coefficients and which coefficients should i use for my equation..

Comment: `ridd$coef` gives the coefficients when the predictor variables have been standardised. The other coefficients are after transforming back to the original scale.

Comment: okay..but which coef to use in the equation to predict mariner...?

Comment: If the predictor values are on the original scale, then use the estimates from `coef(ridd)`.